# Best Way to Build Library Code

Tags: gwt

Suppose I want to create some library code which could be shared across multiple GWT modules.

What is the typical method for reusing this library.  Should I create a module for the library, and then import it inside my .gwt.xml file?  Is there any way to release it as a jar?

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it the way you would do any module. It doesn't have to be a web app, no additional configuration files are needed. Just sources packed up into jar file. The only real requirements are:

1. Follow module creation guidelines:

   1. Prepare a `*.gwt.xml` descriptor file in root dir of your module.
   2. Have a `client` package for classes that are intented to be compiled to js and `server` for the rest.
2. Be sure to include sources in jar file.

What is interesting, if your module does not depend on any GWT-specific classes or use jsni, you can use it with "normal" java applications as well.

The answer to the second question (how to reuse it) is simple: add newly created jar to your classpath and inherit this module in module descriptor of your web app.

And yes, once you have it in a jar, you can release it ;-)

The perfect example of such approach is Ext GWT (aka GXT): http://www.sencha.com/products/extgwt/ just download this library, unpack and see `setup.txt` for installation instructions and how is `gxt.jar` (a reusable module) done.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create GWT modules:

See this tutorial: [GWT Tutorial – Using and creating modules](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=229)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create a New Project (Web Application) and export it as JAR. In this way you have your library outside any other project.

When you export the library as a JAR, don't forget to include the source.

Then to add you library to another project you have to:

1. Add the JAR to the build path.
2. Include a dependency to your library in your module descriptor (com.mycompany.myproject.Myproject.gwt.xml)

`<inherits name='com.mylibrary.mylib.Mylib'/>`

Another things that you can do in your lib is to include server side code, create a theme (including css, images, etc), etc.

This is very useful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is now an Eclipse GWT Module Wizard by Google for just this task!
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/module.html

Generally you create a module and then inherit it in your implementing module. You can implement this in various modules if you like.

Comment: The link you specified doesn't seem to have to do with the question. please elaborate.

Comment: @Rabbi The poster's question was inchoate and demonstrated a prosaic understanding of GWT. How do you make modules and share? Well, you could use the module wizard, and also inherit them. I've add clarification to my answer to limn these basic module implementation facets.