# Create GWT jar from a JSNI class

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I'm trying to convert a Java NativeClass (where I'm using JSNI) to a library that I'll use in Client Side. In the NativeClass I'm declaring just native methods with my JSNI source code.I'm looking for a way make it as `library.jar`

Comment: Do I have to include the NativeClass source code in the Jar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901786/best-way-to-build-library-code/) the response:

1. Create a new GWT Module with a *.gwt.xml descriptor file in root.
2. Put the NativeClass in client package inside your module.
3. Generate your Jar using your module be sure to include your source code. GWT will need this source to generate the client JS.